# Java IAIK Pkcs11 Wrapper generated key is not persisted

Tags: java, pkcs#11

Could anybody help with following problem?

I'm using:

- SoftHSM for Windows
- IAIK Pkcs11 Java Wrapper (v.1.4) to connect to SoftHSM

My Java application generates AES secret key in following steps:

1. PKCS11 Session is opened, login performed.
2. AES key is successfully generated.
3. Searching for this key - and it is found.
4. Closing session.

But if I open new session, I cannot find key anymore - it disappears when I close the session, and is not persisted to HSM.

Do I make something wrong?

Code of application is:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Mechanism;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Module;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Session;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Slot;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Token;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.TokenException;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.objects.AESSecretKey;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.objects.Object;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Constants;

public class GenerateKeyAes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TokenException {

        // Init module and select slot and token
        Module module = Module.getInstance("C:\\prog\\SoftHSM2\\lib\\softhsm2.dll");
        module.initialize(null);
        Slot slot = module.getSlotList(Module.SlotRequirement.TOKEN_PRESENT)[0];
        Token token = slot.getToken();

        // Create session and login
        Session session = token.openSession(Token.SessionType.SERIAL_SESSION, Token.SessionReadWriteBehavior.RW_SESSION,
                null, null);
        session.login(Session.UserType.USER, "1111".toCharArray());

        // Prepare key template
        Mechanism keyGenerationMechanism = Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_AES_KEY_GEN);

        AESSecretKey secretKeyTemplate = new AESSecretKey();
        secretKeyTemplate.getValueLen().setLongValue(new Long(32));
        secretKeyTemplate.getLabel().setCharArrayValue("AES secret 1".toCharArray());
        secretKeyTemplate.getId().setByteArrayValue(new byte[] { 105 });
        secretKeyTemplate.getSign().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
        secretKeyTemplate.getVerify().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
        secretKeyTemplate.getToken().setBooleanValue(Boolean.FALSE);

        // Create key
        AESSecretKey secretKey = (AESSecretKey) session.generateKey(keyGenerationMechanism, secretKeyTemplate);

        System.out.println("Key generated:");
        System.out.println(secretKey.toString());
        System.out.println();

        // Find all objects to ensure that generated key was really created
        AESSecretKey template = new AESSecretKey();
        session.findObjectsInit(template);
        Object[] obs = session.findObjects(10);
        System.out.println("Found objects: " + obs.length);
        System.out.println();

        // Key is found and displayed here!!!
        for (Object ob : obs) {
            System.out.println("Found object:");
            System.out.println(ob);
            System.out.println();
        }

        // Close session
        session.findObjectsFinal();
        session.closeSession();

        // If I open new session here and perform same search - no key is found!

        module.finalize(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PKCS#11 objects can be classified by their lifetime and visibility as:

1. **Token objects** (those with `CKA_TOKEN` attribute set to `true`).
   They are visible to all applications connected to the token that have sufficient permission, and remain on the token even after the sessions (connections between an application and the token) are closed and the token is removed from its slot.
2. **Session objects** (those with `CKA_TOKEN` attribute set to `false`)
   They are more temporary - whenever a session is closed by any means, all session objects created by that session are automatically destroyed. In addition, session objects are only visible to the application which created them.

I am not familiar with IAIK wrapper but it seems you are creating your key as a session object.

I would try changing:

```
secretKeyTemplate.getToken().setBooleanValue(Boolean.FALSE);
```

to

```
secretKeyTemplate.getToken().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
```

See [PKCS#11 v2.20 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/tree/master/v2.20) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was the reason. secretKeyTemplate.getToken().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE) stores secret key.